# How do I clear all Textboxes, Comboboxes, and DateTimePickers on a WinForm in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, textbox, datetimepicker

I'm working in VS 2012 using C# and WinForms for my application, and I'm curious what sort of routine I should use to clear all methods of entering data I have, which includes textboxes, comboboxes, and date time pickers. I've Googled and found a few 'answers', but none seem to work or actually prove helpful.

[EDIT]:

I kept researching and actually found a helpful method that I just had to add some ifs to to get what I wanted:

```
private void ResetFields()
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox tb = (TextBox)ctrl;
                if (tb != null)
                {
                    tb.Text = string.Empty;
                }
            }
            else if (ctrl is ComboBox)
            {
                ComboBox dd = (ComboBox)ctrl;
                if (dd != null)
                {
                    dd.Text = string.Empty;
                    dd.SelectedIndex = -1;
                }
            }
            else if (ctrl is DateTimePicker)
            {
                DateTimePicker dtp = (DateTimePicker)ctrl;
                if (dtp != null)
                {
                    dtp.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are looking for a mechanism that `magically` clears all textboxes etc on your form?

Comment: Yes, of course I was looking for magic... Not an example of a loop to add to my code. I wanted *magic*.

Comment: Not good enough. You have to check all children of children as well. See my answer.

Comment: Well mine seems to be working.

Comment: That's because you don't have nested controls. What if at some point you decide to, say, add a Panel with a Textbox on it? Then it will fail.

Comment: I already have textboxes within panels and it's working. That's why I'm leaving it the way it is.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why it works. (Side note: Welcome to SO. When you respond to someone's _answer_ - they will get a notification. However, when responding to someone's _comment_ - you have to start your comment with "@theirName" for them to get a notification.)

Comment: Just a guess - If you click on "Document outline" (Can be accessed through `View -> Other Windows`) - are the textboxes really on the panel, or are they on the same level as the panel and are actually directly on the Form (And are just in a position inside the panel's area)?

Comment: @ispiro Thanks! I wouldn't have known that otherwise, and I'm not sure why it's working, either, but in programming, if it works, I don't question it. haha Also, upon viewing the document outline, it appears they're within my panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something *like* this:

```
void ClearThem(Control ctrl)
{
    ctrl.Text = "";
    foreach (Control childCtrl in ctrl.Controls) ClearThem(childCtrl);
}
```

And then:

```
ClearThem(this);
```

**Another option:**
Create a class deriving from Panel, with all of what you need on it, and Dock it in the Form. When you need to "refresh" - simply replace that Panel with a new instance of that Panel.

Answer (score 1):

You could just loop in all the controls of the form and clear depending on the control type

Answer (score 1):

We can clear all `Textboxes`, `Comboboxes` but not the `DateTimePicker`

If you want to clear the `DateTimePicker` you must set the properties:
`Format = Custom`, `CustomFormat = " "` and in time that you want to select a date in `DateTimePicker`

```
    private void dateTimePicker1_CloseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
    }
```

And this could be the solution:

```
    public static void ClearAll(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            var texbox = c as TextBox;
            var comboBox = c as ComboBox;
            var dateTimePicker = c as DateTimePicker;

            if (texbox != null)
                texbox.Clear();
            if (comboBox != null)
                comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
            if (dateTimePicker != null)
            {
                dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
                dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = " ";
            }
            if (c.HasChildren)
                ClearAll(c);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Consider dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your form controls, match them to your types and set it to "" or null;